# Indy - Update credential parameter

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I need changue the parameter of a crendential, I want to know if it's neceseary revoke the credential and create againt with the correct parameters or it's posible update a unique parameter in the credential.

The example, there is a error with the average of the transcript schema, Alice must have a 9:

```
transcript_cred_values = json.dumps({
  "first_name": {"raw": "Alice", "encoded": "1139481716457488690172217916278103335"},
  "last_name": {"raw": "Garcia", "encoded": "5321642780241790123587902456789123452"},
  "degree": {"raw": "Bachelor of Science, Marketing", "encoded": "12434523576212321"},
  "status": {"raw": "graduated", "encoded": "2213454313412354"},
  "ssn": {"raw": "123-45-6789", "encoded": "3124141231422543541"},
  "year": {"raw": "2015", "encoded": "2015"},
  "average": {"raw": "5", "encoded": "5"} //This 5 muste be a 9
```

})

But the transcript it's already in the ledger, we need revoke that transcript for changue the parameter and create again?

Answer (score 0):

I can fin the solution in [Hyperledger Indy HIPE](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/hipe/en/latest/text/0011-cred-revocation/README.html#motivation), in the motivation section of the revocations one the reason for use revocations for inputs error in the credentials. Text: "However, it’s also important if a credential gets issued in error (e.g., has a typo in it that misidentifies the subject). The latter case is important even for immutable and permanent credentials such as a birth certificate."

So the solution is revocate and expend a new crencential with the correct parameters for Alice.